# soul dropping some accented letters from the end of words

Tags: accents, soul

I'm using `soul` to letterspace headings in a Hungarian document and compiling it with `lualatex`.

For some reason `soul` drops some of the accented letters at the end of a word, but not all. In the example below, only `ő` and `ű` are affected:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures = TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\so{áll llá ÁLL LLÁ}\\
\so{íll llí ÍLL LLÍ}\\
\so{űll llű ŰLL LLŰ}\\
\so{őll llő ŐLL LLŐ}\\
\so{üll llü ÜLL LLÜ}\\
\so{öll llö ÖLL LLÖ}\\
\so{úll llú ÚLL LLÚ}\\
\so{óll lló ÓLL LLÓ}\\
\so{éll llé ÉLL LLÉ}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample letters]

Comment: The question is not about `ő/Ő`, but rather depends on the fact that they are at the word border. Try with a final `Ű`, for example. Other accented letters seem to be unaffected.

Comment: Indeed! I restated the question.

Comment: I've tracked down the problem to this: characters with Unicode > 255 don't appear. Indeed U+00FF is `ÿ` that is treated correctly, while U+0100, that is `Ā`, disappears.

Comment: TODO  `\SOUL@ttwidth` might also need to be changed, refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142764/250119 / https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341062/250119 ■ in some special cases it might be simpler to avoid `soul` package entirely: letter spacing [fonts - soul package and Cyrillic with xelatex - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625840/soul-package-and-cyrillic-with-xelatex),

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is in the font used for testing hyphenation. If you add

```
\makeatletter
\let\SOUL@tt\relax
\newfontface{\SOUL@tt}{FreeMono}
\makeatother
```

after loading `soul` the problem seems to disappear. It probably won't show again characters that are not in the `\SOUL@tt` font.

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures = TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\usepackage{soul}
\makeatletter
\let\SOUL@tt\relax
\newfontface{\SOUL@tt}{TeX Gyre Cursor}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
\so{áll llá ÁLL LLÁ}\\
\so{íll llí ÍLL LLÍ}\\
\so{űll llű ŰLL LLŰ}\\
\so{őll llő ŐLL LLŐ}\\
\so{üll llü ÜLL LLÜ}\\
\so{öll llö ÖLL LLÖ}\\
\so{úll llú ÚLL LLÚ}\\
\so{óll lló ÓLL LLÓ}\\
\so{éll llé ÉLL LLÉ}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course, a better method would be to use `microtype` for such a job.