# soulutf8 doesn't work with Cyrillic in XeLaTeX

Tags: highlighting, cyrillic, soul

I'm trying to highlight a text written in Russian using `soulutf8` package. In the PDF file, rendered with XeLaTeX, instead of highlighted Russian letters, I've got nothing. With English symbols, it works as expected.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[main=russian, english]{babel}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cm-default]{fontspec}
\setromanfont{PT Sans}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{soulutf8}
\sethlcolor{red}

\begin{document}
Текст на русском для проверки кириллицы.

\hl{Выделенный русский тест}

\hl{Highlighted English text}
\end{document}
```

The result I get:

[image]

Comment: you do not want legacy 8-bit encodings such as T2A with xetex, `\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}` just use `fontspec` and Unicode encodings

Comment: You shouldn't be using `soulutf8` with XeLaTeX. On the other hand, `soul` seems not to be able to deal with Cyrillic characters.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what was suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142764/16578), and also in [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41081/16578), the highlighting of Cyrillic font can be achieved by adding the following lines after `\usepackage{soulutf8}` or `\usepackage{soul}`:

```
\makeatletter
\font\SOUL@tt={LiberationMono}
\setbox\z@\hbox{\SOUL@tt-}
\SOUL@ttwidth\wd\z@
\makeatother
```

or like this:

```
\makeatletter
\let\SOUL@tt\relax
\newfontface{\SOUL@tt}{LiberationMono}
\setbox\z@\hbox{\SOUL@tt-}
\SOUL@ttwidth\wd\z@
\makeatother
```

Here `LiberationMono` is just an axample of TrueType font with support of Cyrillic characters.