# soulutf8 strips characters from compound words

Tags: unicode, hyphenation, soul

I use `soulutf8` for underlining in my LaTeX document. However, it seems to be stripping characters from the end of compound words, e.g.:

```
\ul{$n$-rozměrný}
```

results in

> *n*-rozměrn

However, if I break the word at the hypen, i.e.:

```
\ul{$n$ rozměrný}
```

the 'ý' character re-appears:

> *n* rozměrný

My document is defined as follows:

```
\documentclass[dvips,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[IL2]{fontenc}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
```

A similar problem has already been described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41069/soul-dropping-some-accented-letters-from-the-end-of-words); however, the proposed solution doesn't seem to work in my case.

Comment: Don't use `IL2`, nor `utf8x` nor the `dvips` global option.

Comment: The document is in Czech; removing `IL2` and `utf8x` would make Czech characters disappear.

Comment: No, with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

Comment: The dash - is active in czech and soul doesn't like this. Hide it in an `\mbox` or use `\shorthandoff{-}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is in the fact that `babel-czech` makes the hyphen a shorthand character, but `soul` has no check for an active `-`; the result is that as many characters at the end are mangled as there are hyphens in the text.

Here is a workaround using `regexpatch`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{soulutf8}

\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
\regexpatchcmd*{\SOUL@eval}
  {\cO-}
  {\cA-}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ul{$n$-rozměrný}

\ul{$n$ rozměrný}

\ul{a-b-cd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the IL2 encoding is obsolete and not recommended any more. I'd prefer `utf8` to `utf8x`, as it's more stable.

Without `regexpatch` it's possible too, but quite indirectly.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{soulutf8}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\SOUL@eval}{-}{\SOUL@@@hyphen}{}{}
\patchcmd{\SOUL@eval}{-}{\SOUL@@@hyphen}{}{}
\catcode`-=\active
\patchcmd{\SOUL@eval}{\SOUL@@@hyphen}{-}{}{}
\patchcmd{\SOUL@eval}{\SOUL@@@hyphen}{-}{}{}
\catcode`-=12
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ul{$n$-rozměrný}

\ul{$n$ rozměrný}

\ul{a-b-cd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, the `regexpatch` fixes it (just as the `mbox` proposed in the comments). The main reason I stick with IL2 is that if I use T1 and copy "n-rozměrný" from the output PDF, I get: "n ✲r♦3♠➙r♥ý", whereas everything works OK when the encoding is set to IL2.

Comment: @JohnManak No, if you have a decent TeX distribution with Type1 fonts for the T1 encoded ones. Try adding `\usepackage{lmodern}`. You may want to look also at [Slovak (and Czech) babel gives problems with `\cmidrule` and `\cline`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111999/) for another problem with `babel-czech`.

Comment: I've just been looking into this right now as well and yes, `\usepackage{lmodern}` fixes that problem too.