# Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra } — but shorthands should stay

Tags: babel, soul, russian

I am trying to fix a problem that had not appeared earlier. Maybe the distro got updated...

With TeXLive up to 2015, the following example was working:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\begin{document}
\so{Князь Батог-Батыев}  % Fine
Князь Батог"=Батыев      % Fine
\so{Князь Батог"=Батыев} % Not fine
\end{document}
```

The macro `"=` produces a hyphen that allows breaks in both parts of the compound word.

Now, pdfLaTeX compiler returns an error:

```
! Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.8 \so{Князь Батог"=Батыев}
```

The solutions for similar problems [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/193012/19642), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34670/19642), and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/340661/19642) suggest turning off shorthands. However, I am using the `"=` shorthand throughout the document and do not want to replace `"=` with `-` inside `\so{...}` because, firstly, this used to work, secondly, the words separated with a `"=` have really long parts, so disabling hyphenation in both parts with `-` will have a detrimental effect. Finally, I want to preserve homogeneity: it is highly undesirable to have `\so{Firstname-Secondname}` in remark sub-headings and `Firstname"=Secondname` inside regular paragraphs.

What can be done in this case?

Comment: The only difference I find between TL 2012 and all subsequent releases is that with 2012 I just get “Reconstruction failed”, whereas from TL 2013 on I get the `Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get a difference only between TeX Live 2012 and the subsequent releases. With TL 2012 the error is `Reconstruction Failed`, whereas with TL from 2013 to 2017 I get `Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }`.

You can (and should, in my opinion) use `microtype` for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\so}{\textls[500]}

\begin{document}

\so{Князь Батог-Батыев}

Князь Батог"=Батыев

\so{Князь Батог"=Батыев}

\parbox[t]{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}\so{Князь Батог"=Батыев}}


\end{document}
```

The last `\parbox` is for showing that hyphenation is as expected, before and after `"-`.

[image]

Some adjustment may be needed if the `\so` part starts a paragraph, as you see.

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess `soul` has too many quirks and is outdated, too, so time to switch to modern alternatives...