# How to hightlight the paragraph containing special characters "ą", "č". "ė" etc (with XeLaTex)

Tags: highlighting, soul

Can anyone help me with `\hl` function. How to use it for a paragraph if the text contains Lithuanian letters "ą","į" etc. If the letter is in the middle of the word then it is ok, but some strange things happen when the letter is at the end of word. 
Thank You.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{extarticle}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{lithuanian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage{soul,color}

\makeatletter
\let\SOUL@tt\relax
\newfontface{\SOUL@tt}[Ligatures=TeX]{texgyrecursor-regular.otf}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\hl{Here is some text in Lithuanian. When the special character is in the middle "sąryšis" of the word then "hl" works good and "mbox" is not necessary but if the word ends with special character "mergaitė glostė katę" then special characters "ė", "ė" and "ę" (and other š, ą, ų, į etc) are omitted and "mbox" fixes that although "mbox" does not break the line.  
  }
\end{document}
```

The code does not work with XeLaTex and TexMaker. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I am quite raw in latex. If the problem is very similar so what in my code should be added to solve the problem. I do not use 
`\usepackage{fontspec}`
`\setmainfont[Ligatures = TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}`

Comment: Dear reviewers eager to close this posting: The other thread may identify the problem, but I don't see how the answer supplied there solves this problem, at least not in a direct way without requiring additional knowledge about available and used fonts. Maybe the next one voting for closure could post a solution before?

Comment: @Rasa Just add the four lines in my answer after the loading of `soul` (and before `\begin{document}`), you're done. Depending on your font setup you may need to change `TeX Gyre Cursor` into `texgyrecursor-regular.otf`

Comment: @egreg On TexLive 2016, last updated today, I can verify the issue with `xelatex` as well as `lualatex`: ė vanishes (though not ę). Adding the four lines from the other thread does not solve the problem, even after changing the font name: Both processors yield the error `Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed.` So I'd not consider this issue as resolved.

Comment: @gernot I agree

Comment: @gernot I think `soul` is fundamentally broken with XeLaTeX

Comment: Depending on how important it is to use `soul`, consider switching to `pdflatex` (instead of `xelatex` or `lualatex`) using the preamble `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[L7x]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,lithuanian]{babel}
\usepackage{soulutf8,color}` (instead of `polyglossia` etc).

Comment: I added four lines as suggested, changed to ` texgyrecursor-regular.otf`. Nothing good with xelatex (Xelatex is necessary  for my fonts). Maybe there is any other idea how to highlight the new inserts or changes made in documents?

Answer (score 2):

With lmmono and if I add the code to reset the width of the hyphen your example compile:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{extarticle}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{lithuanian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\font\SOUL@tt="LMMono10-Regular"
\setbox\z@\hbox{\SOUL@tt-}
\SOUL@ttwidth\wd\z@ %
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%\tracingmacros=1
\hl{Here is some text in Lithuanian. When the special character is in the middle "sąryšis" of the word then "hl" works good and "mbox" is not necessary but if the word ends with special character "mergaitė glostė katę" then special characters "ė", "ė" and "ę" (and other š, ą, ų, į etc) are omitted and "mbox" fixes that although "mbox" does not break the line.
  }
\end{document}
```

Your example also compile for me with lualatex. Imho this looks like a rounding problem.

Comment: But if I want to add for example `\citep{Bernstein2001}` in `\hl{...}` it says "error that there is extra '}'". So a new problem occurs.

Comment: That's not specific to xelatex. A lot commands are problematic in a soul command. Put it in a box.

Comment: Thank You, it worked. The `\hl` function is just for marking the changes. It's a pity that many things I will have to delete to eliminate the markings.

Comment: This is a hideous hack, but it seems to work with LuaLaTeX… Thanks! :-)