# Turkish characters do not appear end of the word

Tags: unicode, characters, turkish

I am preparing a latex document which should use Times New Roman font and should support Turkish characters. In the pre-toc part of document there are some kind of title pages and i had to use red, bold, underlined and centered headings. Only problem in these heading parts if a Turkish character is at the end of a word it doesn't show. Other than end of a word in heading or anywhere in normal text it shows. I am using xelatex for times new roman support.

This outputs as **Öğrencinin Çalışt Kurum ile İlgili Bilgiler**

```
 {\centering
  \textcolor{red}{\bfseries \ul{Öğrencinin Çalıştığı Kurum ile İlgili Bilgiler}}
  \\[1\baselineskip]
  \par}
```

This outputs as **Öğrencinin Çalıştığık Kurum ile İlgili Bilgiler**

```
 {\centering
  \textcolor{red}{\bfseries \ul{Öğrencinin Çalıştığık Kurum ile İlgili Bilgiler}}
  \\[1\baselineskip]
  \par}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I guess it's the same problem as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41069/4427

Comment: However, it seems to choke with the dotless i. :-(

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41069/4427 This does not solve my problem unfortunately