# Cyrillic characters don't appear when enclosed by \ul with soulutf8

Tags: cyrillic, soul

MWE:

```
\documentclass[17pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\setmainfont{LMR12R-Gregory}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\setotherlanguage{russian}
\setul{}{2pt}
\begin{document}
    \ul{Привет}
\end{document}
```

Output (it's the tiny vertical line in the picture):

[image: Code output]

Is there a way to make this work as one would expect?

Comment: You must set the internal ttf font to a font that contains cyrillic, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41081/2388 (and you don't need soulutf8, soul works fine with lualatex).