# soul package and Cyrillic with xelatex

Tags: fonts, xetex, cyrillic, soul

How to handle Cyrillic ymbols with `soul` package?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
    \setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
    \setmonofont{Liberation Mono}
    \setmainlanguage{ukrainian}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\begin{document}
    \mainmatter
    Короткий зміст\par
    Brief content\par
    \so{Короткий зміст}\par
    \so{Brief content}
\end{document}
```

Compile with

```
xelatex test.tex
```

[image]

I assume that this is caused by the absence of Cyrillic characters in the *internal* font used by `soul` package. It is possible to set this font with `\font\SOUL@tt=` but I don't know how I can use a font with this command.

I added `\tracinglostchars=2` and saw this:

```
Missing character: There is no К in font ectt1000!
Missing character: There is no о in font ectt1000!
...
Missing character: There is no с in font ectt1000!
Missing character: There is no т in font ectt1000!
```

Comment: Is XeLaTeX a hard requirement or would you consider changing to LuaLaTeX? For the latter the excellent `lua-ul` package handles underlining flawlessly.

Comment: And instead of `\so` you could use `\textls` provided by the `microtype` package in LuaTeX.

Comment: @Skillmon I use XeTeX because I have a book typeset in XeTeX and I can't easily change to another system.

Comment: Are you sure that LuaTeX doesn't work (the two are similar enough that most things should out of the box)? It should be possible to make `soul` work for you: You'll have to find a monospaced font that contains all characters you need.

Comment: see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41081/7674)

Comment: Special case of [accents - soul dropping some accented letters from the end of words - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41069/soul-dropping-some-accented-letters-from-the-end-of-words). But looks like there's another solution specific to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can locally add the `LetterSpace` feature.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

%\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}} % not needed
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\setmonofont{Liberation Mono}
\setmainlanguage{ukrainian}

\NewDocumentCommand{\so}{m}{%
  {\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=10,Ligatures=NoCommon}#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

Короткий зміст

Brief content ffi ffl

\so{Короткий зміст}

\so{Brief content ffi ffl}

Короткий зміст

Brief content ffi ffl

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `Ligatures=NoCommon` is necessary with fonts having ligatures, as the following example with Libertinus Serif instead of Liberation shows:

[image]

Beware that stealing sheep is not considered good practice.

I know that it's common with Cyrillic to letter space also lower case for emphasis, but letter spacing Latin letters is not considered good typography.

Comment: I'm looking into sources of `soul` and see `\let\so\textso` where `\textso` is defined via `\sodef` so it has not only `\SOUL@soletterskip` but also `\SOUL@soinnerskip` and `\SOUL@soouterskip`. Seems like I need to know how to convert 3 `\sodef` parameters into `LetterSpace`,, maybe `WordSpace`, something else.

Answer (score 2):

Using LuaLaTeX and the `microtype` package you could use `\textls` instead of `\so`. If you also need highlighting, underlining or strike through of `soul` you could instead use the `lua-ul` package in LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[letterspace=200]{microtype}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
    \setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
    \setmonofont{Liberation Mono}
    \setmainlanguage{ukrainian}
\begin{document}
    \mainmatter
    Короткий зміст\par
    Brief content\par
    \textls{Короткий зміст}\par
    \textls{Brief content}
\end{document}
```

[image]